# Pictures Covering Home Theater Speakers

Tags: materials, home-theater, speakers, audio, sounds

So I have some in wall speakers that I've installed. I would like to put pictures in front of them. I was thinking that a silk screen or similar should have essentially no sound distortion.

I reason that most speakers have cloth grilles anyway surely I could find something similar?

I was just wondering if anyone has insight on a material that I should use?

Comment: The question is off-topic for this network, but how does one present "pictures" on fabric?

Comment: The cloth grill is to help avoid the element / speaker internals from getting damaged. If you put anything in front of a speaker (grill or something else) you will distort the sound.. It depends how much you can live with.  This is one of those situations where you just try it and see for yourself. Hold something in place where it would be, and listen yourself. See what you are ok with.

Comment: @isherwood Any suggestion as to where this should go? This is the only network that I could find pertaining to home theater...

Comment: I'm not sure how you can expect objective answers. As Eric said, it's a matter of prerogative what you'll tolerate. Most fabrics won't significantly mute sound, but you have to decide for yourself. Plus, the question has been asked and [answered](http://www.audiogurus.com/learn/speakers/speaker-cloth-grille-fabric/1692), and [answered](https://boomspeaker.com/acoustic-cloth-for-speakers/)....

Comment: I'm maybe going to blow your mind a little and show you the world of [exciters](http://www.daytonaudio.com/index.php/loudspeaker-components/loudspeaker-drivers-by-series/exciters.html).  You can turn the pictures _into_ speakers.  Have fun with that knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Googling "acoustically transparent fabric" returns a variety of companies that provide materials that advertise the characteristics you require. For example:

https://fabricmate.com/fabric/acoustic-fabrics/
or
https://www.audimute.com/what-is-acoustic-fabric

Transparent cloth is available but putting a picture on it is another challenge. The printing process needs to be one that does not reduce the ability of the cloth to let air pass through it. Painting for example would change the acoustic properties.

The people at audimute build sound absorbing panels with a customizable picture. Maybe they can build a panel with your picture that is transparent.

It would be great to hear how this comes out for you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer; keep 'em coming!